# Will this amplifier connect these speakers to my PC?

Tags: pc, audio, speakers, music, amplifiers

I found some Canton passive speakers and connected them with an audio jack cable to my PC but nothing happened.
[image]
I did some research and found out that these are passive speakers and they need an amplifier.

Then I looked for an amplifier on Amazon and found this:

[image]

I thought amplifiers were big chunks so I am not sure this little thing does the work of the middleman to play music from my laptop to the speakers.

The amp Amazon link: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B01LY7RYQO/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=verst%C3%A4rker&qid=1586534369&sr=8-10

Do you know if that amp will work and what else do I need to make this work?

Comment: It may or may not work & you might not find sound quality acceptable if it did. Amp ratings should specify A) RMS power out, B) THD (Total Harmonic Distortion) at that power level, and C) output impedance over 20Hz-20,000Hz. Your speakers have 4-8 Ohms impedance w/ a max of 50-100W per channel . A search at Amazon for what you showed us https://www.amazon.com/s?k=Elegiant+30+W+*+2+Mini+Bluetooth+Amplifier+Aluminium+2.0 didn't find an amp matching the picture. Maybe I'm in a different country? Please include the web link to a 50W or larger amp by clicking [edit] and adding it to the question.

Comment: @K7AAY your guess was right - the product is from another country. I have just added its link to my question. For convenience, you can also find it here: https://www.amazon.de/-/en/dp/B01LY7RYQO/ref=sr_1_10?dchild=1&keywords=verst%C3%A4rker&qid=1586534369&sr=8-10

Please note that the page is in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cable for dual RCA jack audio output and also for 3.5mm ring-sleeve-tip auto jack output is included with the device, as is the power supply, so it's complete.

For one Euro less, I would go for the https://www.amazon.de/dp/B07W4JHGKS/ which includes the 3.5mm cable and delivers 50W RMS, but the reviews on the product you chose show it's acceptable.

For either, replacing the 12VDC power supply with a 24VDC power supply would provide more volume.

Both are digital amps so you won't get the 'golden sound' an audiophile would want, but I'd accept it.